# sql query limit the search and not the result

Tags: mysql, sql

SQL Limit query will search the entire table and then limit the result according to our parameters, but I want the query to search from a particular row number to another row number.Is it possible to limit the search too ?

Comment: Unless you specify `ORDER BY` rows do not have numbers.

Comment: I have already assigned the row numbers,but I want the search query to start from a particular row and not from the beginning

Comment: Where and how did you assign them? You mean you have auto-increment ID column?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `DISTINCT` alongside `LIMIT row_count`, mysql will stop searching after finding `row_count` unique rows, even if there aren't indexed columns. See [third dot](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html).

So you could query like this:
`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM foo OFFSET start_row_count LIMIT end_row_count`

Then you could even stop specifying the row numbers by yourself if you deem beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the additional detail in the comment you provided, I'm assuming there's a column within your table that designates the "row number" you are trying to limit. If that is true, then use the [BETWEEN operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between) in your query's WHERE clause. This will limit the search to only include rows that are within the range you specify.

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE row_number BETWEEN x AND y;
```

Comment: It will limit the `output`. It will limit the `search` only if this column is indexed.

Comment: True enough. The assumption baked into this answer is that the original poster has set up the table with the appropriate index for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
WHERE Row_Number > 64
```